Extend holomorphism from $U$ to $\hat{U_{\Omega}}$
We have $U \subset \Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ open sets, and $f$ holomorphic in $U$. Assume that we have a sequence $(f_n)$ with $f_n \in \mathcal{O}(\Omega)$ converging uniformly to $f$ on each compact subset of $U$. Show that there exists some $g$ holomorphic in $\hat{U_{\Omega}}$ and $g|U = f$.
Here $\hat{U_{\Omega}}$ means $U$ unioning all connected components of $\Omega - U$ that are relatively compact.
So the original statement is an iff one, and I showed the other direction by using Runge's theorem. But I am now confused on how to find a holomorphic extension of f onto $\hat{U_{\Omega}}$. It is attempting to use $g = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n$, but we do not have uniform convergence outside $U$, and therefore cannot use Weierstrass to show holomorphism there. I am thinking of using the fact that on each connected component $C$, I have uniform convergence on $\partial C$, then try to apply the Maximum Principle to it. Is this the right way to proceed?
